# LEGO bag with no instructions or box

Tags: instructions

It's bag #2 and the only # I can find is 135149 and a date of 2011.
There are 2 mini bags inside the large bag.
It has some very long grey pieces and 2 blue wall looking pieces.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to identify the set. Can you add a picture?

Comment: Number and date identify the plastic bag design, but not the set nor the pieces in the bag, so that info doesn't help us (apart from eliminating sets that were no longer produced in 2011). We'd need a picture as per Alex' comment.

Answer (score 7):

It is from '4645 Harbour' which was produced in 2011 and bag 2 contains blue wall panels and stone grey 1x10s.

[image: Harbour]

Instructions can be found [here](http://lego.brickinstructions.com/lego_instructions/set/4645/Harbour_).

Comment: I'm hoping Kevin can confirm your findings, but that's a pretty awesome find based on the meagre description provided.